# Dailymotion issue while logout

Tags: dailymotion-api

Once after revoking the session after logout in Daily motion app.
When user logins again page is redirecting to permissions page instead of login page.How to get rid of this awkward situation?

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is normal, because you are already logged in Dailymotion.
If you logout from Dailymotion website, and you go to the app the oauth authorization window will ask for credentials.

This behavior is the same with Facebook 3-legged Oauth.